# How to loop in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to loops in R. I'd like to iterate through dataframes which are numbered sequentially to perform an action on them.

The dataframes are called total and are numbered sequentially to 15:

```
total1
total2
total3
```

etc.

I'd like to simply find out how to print the names of these objects from a loop so I can use this as a starting point to perform other actions on them. At the moment all I'm doing is:

```
for (n in 1:15)
{print total[n]
}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
Error: object 'total' not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I have already created all the total dataframes.

Comment: If you want to print object names `ls(pattern='total\\d+')` or wrapping with `cat`, `cat(ls(pattern='total\\d+'), sep="\n")`

Comment: OK but really I'm asking about how to create a loop so that I can reference the dataframe within the loop based on the value of n for that iteration eg total10 etc

Comment: print was the simplest example I could think of

Comment: What I am trying to convey is that you don't need a loop.  `for(n in 1:15) print(paste0('total', n))`

Comment: OK but what if I then want to do something like total15$V1 * 8. I was asking for an example so I can run more complex loops. I did say this in the question

Comment: You can do that with `mget` to return a list.  `lst <- mget(ls(pattern='total\\d+')); lapply(lst, transform, newCol=V1*8)`

Comment: @akrun can you post as an answer

Comment: you can find this interesting: http://blog.datacamp.com/tutorial-on-loops-in-r/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have multiple objects with the pattern `total` followed by some numbers, we could get the object names in the global environment by `ls` and specifying the `pattern` argument.  We get the values stored in the objects in a `list` using `mget`.  Suppose, we want to add a new column, we can use `lapply` to loop through the `list` and create a new column with `transform`

```
 lst <- mget(ls(pattern='total\\d+'))
 lst1 <- lapply(lst, transform, newCol=V1*8)
```

I would keep the data.frames within the `list` itself instead of updating the objects in the global environment.  Suppose if you need to do that

```
 list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

It is not recommended as most of the operations can be done within the `list` including writing it to a new file or existing one.  Also, it might be better to read all the files in a `list` using `lapply/read.table` rather than creating multiple objects in the global environment.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is spot on: there’s no object called `total`. Rather, you have objects `total1` …. To fix this, put your `data.frame`s into a list rather than numbering them by appending indices:

```
total = list(
    first_data_frame,
    second_data_frame,
    …
)
```

I’m assuming you’re generating/loading your `data.frame`s from some source, so putting them into a list rather than separate variables should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
names <- paste("total", 1:15, sep="")
names[1]
names[15]
names[1:15]
```